# PowerBi Rankx returning only 1 irrespective of category

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

I am trying to get the rank based on the category in powerbi , But not getting the result as expected[image].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by measure. Use ALLEXCEPT filter.

[image]

Comment: Can you pls explain how the ALLEXCEPT worked for this scenario?

Comment: ALLEXCEPT applies filter only to Dept_NO column and removes all other filters. So, rank will get filtered by Dept_NO

Answer (score 0):

Use Table in place of column in ALL filter

```
rank = RANKX(ALL('Sheet1'), sum(Sheet1[sal]))
```

Comment: But i want the ranking based on the Dept_no